# How to check if two structs have the same generic parameter type in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics

While checking out this repository https://github.com/Samasaur1/DiceKit I stumbled on following piece of code implementing Comparable/Hashable this way:

```
public struct DieSide<OutputType: Hashable>: Hashable {

    public let value: OutputType

    // snip

    public static func == (lhs: DieSide, rhs: DieSide) -> Bool { //IMPORTANT NOTE: THIS DOES NOT ACCEPT DieSides WITH DIFFERENT GENERIC ARGUMENTS
        guard type(of: lhs.value) == type(of: rhs.value) else {
            return false
        }
        return lhs.value == rhs.value
    }

    // snip
}
```

You can find the code [here](https://github.com/Samasaur1/DiceKit/blob/d67f52f6d2b483180814644cd1d96edb97e060d1/Sources/DiceKit/DieSide.swift#L17).

I believe this check could be done on the language level using where clause instead of checking the types of the arguments in the code and especially - so the comment won't be necessary anymore.

One approach I tried is this one, but that clearly doesn't work (Neither type in same-type constraint ('error type' or 'error type') refers to a generic parameter or associated type):

```
public static func == (lhs: DieSide, rhs: DieSide) -> Bool where lhs.value.Type == rhs.value.Type {
    return lhs.value == rhs.value
}
```

I also searched for similar answers but was able to find solutions for languages other than Swift at the moment.

Any help on accessing the generic parameters' types appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The guard statement in that code is pointless. It is impossible for `type(of: lhs.value) == type(of: rhs.value)` to be `false`.

The first of these is just shorthand for the second.

```swift
public static func == (lhs: DieSide, rhs: DieSide) -> Bool {
  lhs.value == rhs.value
}

public static func == (lhs: DieSide<OutputType>, rhs: DieSide<OutputType>) -> Bool {
  lhs.value == rhs.value
}
```

(You can also use `Self` instead of `DieSide`.)

Comment: BTW do you mind if I create a pull request with a link back here?

Comment: No, anything I put on Stack Overflow is free to use for any non-nefarious purpose. 